# How to set name dynamically within Quasar Component

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework

I want to create a bunch of q-input variables into a form (from objects) and read them when the user clicks on the submit button.

-- main program

```
<script setup>

const one = {
name: 'first',
value: 'one'
}

const two = {
name: 'second',
value: 'two'
}

function onSubmit(e){
    const formData = new FormData(e.target)
    for (const [name, value] of formdata.entries()){
        data.push({
            name,
            value
        })
    }
    console.log(data)
</script>

<template>
...
<Child :testProps="one" />
<Child :testProps="two" />
<q-btn type="submit" />
</template>
```

-- child program

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
...
...
const props = defineProps(['testprops'])

const newValue = ref('')
newValue.value = props.testProps.value

const newName = ref('')
newName.value = props.testProps.name

</script>

<template>
    ...
    ...
    <q-input type="text" :name="newName" v-model="newValue" />
</template>
```

My problem is that Quasar is not setting the name correctly in the resulting HTML so I cannot get the name and value from the onSubmit from the main program.

Is there another way where I can set the name or id inside the q-input dynamically so that I can recognize them in the main program?